# jquery sortable widget inArray loop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, for-loop, jquery-ui-sortable

Can any one help me with `jQuery sortable.`
The code bellow creates array:

```
 order = ["Layer1", "Layer2", "Layer0"].
```

That is in the right order but for loop gives

```
 result: Layer0, Layer1, Layer2.
```

This happens when i drag last created list item, why isn't `Layer2` between `Layer1` and `Layer0`?
Why the loop is not in the order `Layer1`, `Layer2`, `Layer0`?

```
window.onload = function(){
$(function() {
var idsInOrder=$("#myLayers").sortable({
  update: function(event, ui) {
         var changedList = this.id;
         var order = $("#myLayers").sortable('toArray');
        for(var a=0; a<=n; a++){
           k=a.toString();    
           var u=jQuery.inArray( "Layer"+k, order );
           console.log("Layer"+k );
  }
},

});
 $("#myLayers").disableSelection();
});
};
```

Comment: i will recommend to use  http://underscorejs.org/

Comment: You are using first state of sortable on each step. You can see my answer and demo [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262620/jquery-sortable-widget-inarray-loop/24263140#24263140)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/ATCgV/)**

Because, you are using first initialized sortable object. You can use following implementation;

**HTML:**

```
    <ul id="myLayers">
        <li class="ui-state-default" id="1"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Layer 1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default" id="2"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Layer 2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default" id="3"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Layer 3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default" id="4"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Layer 4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default" id="5"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Layer 5</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default" id="6"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Layer 6</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default" id="7"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Layer 7</li>
    </ul>
<b>Status:</b>
<div id="status"></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
  var idsInOrder=$("#myLayers").sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
        var layers = [];
        $('#myLayers li').each( function(e) {
            layers.push( ( $(this).index() + 1 )  + '= Layer ' +  $(this).attr('id'));
        });
        var positions = layers.join("<br/>")
        $("#status").html(positions);
      }

  });
  $("#myLayers").disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: An approval will be appreciated :)